# How to get longer compile times in PHP

Tags: php, opcache

I was wondering how can I write a PHP script that needs a **longer compile time**?

I want to do this to **test** in the OPCache extension works.

Later edit:
When a PHP script is loading, the code is compiled into bytecode and this bytecode will be interpreted by CPU. The compilation process usually takes some milliseconds but I need to make this time extremely large to test the OPCache extension from PHP 5.5. This extension should cache the script bytecode so that it won't need to compile the script again.

Comment: Do you mean execution time or are you compiling a php script to make an archive?

Comment: I will clarify my question.

Comment: Use github and find large php projects

Comment: I tried. How long should it be? ^_^

Comment: From your last update. Php5.5 has built in opcode caching

Comment: Yes. But I want to test if it works.

Comment: Check your memory use. It should go up by a consistent number

Comment: I saw that the size of the memory grew up because of this script but I still see the same compile time on the output.

Comment: How are you testing the compile time ?

Comment: I test it using `microtime()` function at the beginning of the file and another one at the end of the file. Then I make the difference between those two.

Comment: Then your testing it wrong. Your testing execution time there

Comment: You are right. Then how can I find the compile times?

Answer (score 1):

As @PaulCrovella said in the comments, what I needed was ApacheBench.

By using the command `ab http://localhost/index.php` on a script with about 600.000 lines of code, the results were:

On the first benchmark test:

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.9
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index.php
Document Length:        4927 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.944 seconds
Complete requests:      1
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      5116 bytes
HTML transferred:       4927 bytes
Requests per second:    1.06 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       944.054 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       944.054 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          5.29 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:   944  944   0.0    944     944
Waiting:      939  939   0.0    939     939
Total:        944  944   0.0    944     944
```

On the second benchmark test:

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.9
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index.php
Document Length:        4927 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.047 seconds
Complete requests:      1
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      5116 bytes
HTML transferred:       4927 bytes
Requests per second:    21.28 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       47.003 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       47.003 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          106.29 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:    47   47   0.0     47      47
Waiting:       43   43   0.0     43      43
Total:         47   47   0.0     47      47
```